# pg_query error because of name: 'kill 'em all'

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pg-query

pg_query can't be executed in the case where name = ' Kill 'em all ' the error is pointing at the " ' " before "em" which is the problem but i can't find a solution.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO order (foodid,name) VALUES ($food_id,'$food')";
$result = pg_query($conn,$query) or die("Query cannot be executed");
```

Comment: it is because that particular name  contains `'` to pass it to database query should be replaced with `\'`. If you got problems here you  should really take look on topic of "SQL Injection" and SQL queries with parameters to avoid further headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're passing the string

```
INSERT INTO order (foodid,name) VALUES (1,' Kill 'em all')
```

to the postgresql server, which has no chance to determine that the ' in `'em` is part of the string literal and not its delimiter.
You have to make sure your payload parameters do not "break" the sql statement.

You can do that either by using the [appropriate encoding/escaping function for string literals](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-literal.php) to put the payload directly into the sql statement

```
// <--- test whether $food_id contains only digits here, e.g. via ctype_digit
$query = sprintf('
    INSERT INTO
        order (foodid,name)
    VALUES
        (%s,%s)',
    $food_id, pg_escape_literal($conn, $food)
);

$result = pg_query($conn,$query) or die("Query cannot be executed");
```

or using a [prepared statement + parameters](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php), in effect separating the actual sql statement from the payload data:

```
// Prepare a query for execution
$result = pg_prepare($conn, '', '
    INSERT INTO
        order (foodid,name)
    VALUES
        ($1,$2)
');
if ( !$result ) {
    yourErrorHandler();
}
$result = pg_execute($conn, '', array($food_id, $foo));
if ( !$result ) {
    yourErrorHandler();
}
```

see also: http://php.net/security.database.sql-injection

Comment: Thnx for the info. Worked like a charm.